# How Can I Unplace Tkinter Lable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to remove a lable that i placed

i'am searching for a solution for one hour longer .

can someone help me i'l be glad

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely remove the widget, you can call `destroy` on the widget. This will cause it to be removed from the screen, and the label object itself will be destroyed.

```
the_label = tk.Label(...)
...
the_label.destroy()
```

If you just want to remove it from view and possibly add it back later, the method to remove it depends on how you added it to the window. You can use one of `place_forget`, `pack_forget`, `grid_forget`, or `grid_remove`.

```
the_label = tk.Label(...)
the_label.place(...)
...
the_label.place_forget()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply destroy the label with code as below

```
label.destroy()
```